# Jmeter testing: How to generate many unique files?

Tags: file, jmeter, generate

I have question：How to generate many unique files ? In my testing: upload many files to gofast，but File content is not repeating. Thank you !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLfSn.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's about JMeter, personally I would go for pre-generating test files using operating system built-in mechanisms like [shell scripting](https://www.shellscript.sh/) and referencing them using [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) because I want the test to be **repeatable**

However if you're looking for a JMeter-specific solution you can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and Groovy language for creating the file with some content

Example simple code:

```
def file = new File('foo.txt') 
file << 'bar'
vars.put('myFile', file.getAbsolutePath())
```

The code:

- creates an empty file `foo.txt` in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
- writes "bar" message to it
- stores the full path to the file into `myFile` JMeter Variable

So you should be able to refer to it as `${myFile}` instead of hard-coding the file path.

P.S. There is a better way of taking screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I update my question:

I have a file,file format and content is:

```
> 20210126000880000003|3|33.00|20210126|15:30
>         1|20210126000000000000000000002207|1220210126080109|1000|100000000000000319|100058110000000325|402041000012|402041000012|PT07|621067000000123645|收款方户名|2021-01-26|2021-01-26|10.00|TN|NCS|12|875466
>         2|20210126000000000000000000002208|1220210126080110|1000|100000000000000319|100058110000000325|402041000012|402041000012|PT06|621067000000123645|收款方户名|2021-01-26|2021-01-26|20.00|TN|NCS|12|875466
>         3|20210126000000000000000000002209|1220210126080111|1000|100000000000000319|100058110000000325|402041000012|402041000012|PT08|621067000000123645|收款方户名|2021-01-26|2021-01-26|3.00|TN|NCS|12|875466
```

I have two question:

1: I want to generate 50,000 same files in
Windows.use cp and echo command in linux system.how to generate 50,000
same files in Windows?

2: next step: modify row one and Column one;row
two and Column two;row two and column three.set the three numbers
remain unique(the three numbers in each file cannot be repeated).
such as:
"20210126000880000003";"20210126000000000000000000002207";"1220210126080109".

I want to use sed command。how to modify it？Thanks!